# VS2010 Beta1 Performance Sessions

Tags: visual-studio

Just a quick question, does anyone know if there are restrictions on creating Performance Sessions in VS2010 that weren't there in 2008? I've got an existing Solution I've upgraded and the 'Create Performance Session' option is disabled on right clicking of my unit tests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be some misconfiguration or another issue on your machine because it is working on mine:

[alt text http://bqqqkg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1phtHGp7VC-zDCZM7NEWq1JGQ6IAeXp1f6LkxdrCRdEc8elu4Rue6_skBSRTY-iqQpTbWcxm8L1XZda9GSowof6WbwKsivyh3j/PerformanceSession2.jpg](http://bqqqkg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1phtHGp7VC-zDCZM7NEWq1JGQ6IAeXp1f6LkxdrCRdEc8elu4Rue6_skBSRTY-iqQpTbWcxm8L1XZda9GSowof6WbwKsivyh3j/PerformanceSession2.jpg)

[alt text http://bqqqkg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pzkz9kBZB7RH3okqHoeKRFO0C3RWIU4Ld_IwFSvJ42K3PnpN3DL1A1PtSs-LfQLgaH2DjrD_bwhe4-rp48K0c6rWHp87itl8F/PerformanceSession.jpg](http://bqqqkg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pzkz9kBZB7RH3okqHoeKRFO0C3RWIU4Ld_IwFSvJ42K3PnpN3DL1A1PtSs-LfQLgaH2DjrD_bwhe4-rp48K0c6rWHp87itl8F/PerformanceSession.jpg)

Comment: Hmm, did you install the whole lot? I stuck to just a few components but it would be strange if it were in any of the packages I excluded from the installation.